# In Java HtmlUnit how do I add an hidden input to a form?

Tags: htmlunit

I cannot instantiate [HtmlHiddenInput](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlHiddenInput.html) and use the appendChild method to the form object, because the former has no constructor. Is there a better way rather than doing that in JavaScript? I'd like to keep javascript disabled to save on resources.

Comment: HtmlUnit is a testing framework, not a DOM manipulation framework. This is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I know. But I need to do massive web scraping and wasn't able to find something better than HtmlUnit with JavaScript support. Screen scraping is not an option for me, too slow. Anyway this is the only case where I need a bit of DOM manipulation: I just want to inject a "max-results" parameter from the first request to get more results on the first result page already.

Answer (score 3):

This is the official way to do it:

```
// where htmlPage is the current page you're on
// and internalForm is the form you want to append the field to
HtmlElement createdElement = htmlPage.createElement("input");
createdElement.setAttribute("type", inputName);
createdElement.setAttribute("name", name);
createdElement.setAttribute("value", value);
internalForm.appendChild(createdElement);
```

Comment: this is how I do it too.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I'd like to be able to write (where f is an HtmlForm, p an HtmlPage, b a WebClient):

```
HashMap a = new HashMap();
a.put("name", "concealed");
a.put("value", "secret");
f.appendChild(new HtmlHiddenInput(p,a));
```

But since HtmlHiddenInput cannot be instantiated I had to fall-back on JavaScript, which is slower and uglier:

```
bool j = b.isJavaScriptEnabled();
if (!j) { b.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); }

p.executeJavaScript(
    "{" +
    "    var" +
    "        d = document," +
    "        i = d.createElement('input');" +
    "    with (i) {" +
    "        name = 'concealed';" +
    "        type = 'hidden';" +
    "        value = 'secret';" +
    "    }" +
    "    d.getElementsByName('form1')[0].appendChild(i);" +
    "}");

if (!j) { b.setJavaScriptEnabled(false); }
```

IMHO sometimes too strict constraints get in the way. I do not see a good reason why instantiating an HtmlHiddenInput should be forbidden.

Comment: If this is part of your question, then add it to the question - don't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with HtmlFileInput and had found a workaround via InputElementFactory:

```
    HtmlPage page;
    ...
    AttributesImpl attrs = new AttributesImpl();
    attrs.addAttribute("", "type", "type", "", "hidden");
    HtmlElement el = InputElementFactory.instance.createElement(page, "input", attrs);
    HtmlHiddenInput hiddenInput = (HtmlHiddenInput) el;
```